# can't run dynamic backpropagation in neuroph studio 2.85

Tags: java, image-processing, neural-network

I'm new to neural networks.

I've created neural network in neuroph studio 2.85. There are 14 inputs neurons, 14 hidden neurons and 3 output neurons. I've used dynamic backpropagation as learning method. when I click on train button of backpropagation setting dialog it shows following error in ide.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.neuroph.netbeans.main.easyneurons.dialog.BackpropagationTrainingDialog.train(BackpropagationTrainingDialog.java:611)
at org.neuroph.netbeans.main.easyneurons.dialog.BackpropagationTrainingDialog.trainButtonActionPerformed(BackpropagationTrainingDialog.java:508)
at org.neuroph.netbeans.main.easyneurons.dialog.BackpropagationTrainingDialog.access$000(BackpropagationTrainingDialog.java:21)
at org.neuroph.netbeans.main.easyneurons.dialog.BackpropagationTrainingDialog$1.actionPerformed(BackpropagationTrainingDialog.java:108)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
[catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1651)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1603)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
at org.neuroph.netbeans.toolbar.TrainToolbarAction.showMLPTrainingDialog(TrainToolbarAction.java:92)
at org.neuroph.netbeans.toolbar.TrainToolbarAction.actionPerformed(TrainToolbarAction.java:66)
at org.openide.awt.InjectorExactlyOne.actionPerformed(InjectorExactlyOne.java:78)
at org.openide.awt.ContextAction$Performer.actionPerformed(ContextAction.java:226)
at org.openide.awt.ContextManager.actionPerformed(ContextManager.java:257)
at org.openide.awt.ContextAction.actionPerformed(ContextAction.java:109)
at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker$1.run(ActionInvoker.java:93)
at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker.doPerformAction(ActionInvoker.java:116)
at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker.invokeAction(ActionInvoker.java:99)
at org.openide.awt.GeneralAction$BaseDelAction.actionPerformed(GeneralAction.java:234)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I do not know what is going wrong with it.

Comment: Please show the line of code in which you get the exception.

Comment: Error is not in my code. it is in the ide (neuroph studio 2.85).